# Бинарное дерево. Эффективный алгоритм подсчёта значений всех вершин правого поддерева каждой вершины

Tags: java, алгоритм, рекурсия, бинарное-дерево

Пример работы алгоритма:

```
                       Tree:
                        16 (sum 48)
                    /       \
          sum(19) 10        18 (sum 25)
                /   \       /  \
        sum(0) 3     19    5    25
                   sum(0) sum(0)  sum(0)
```

Для каждой вершины дерева считается сумма всех значений правого поддерева. Каждый узел имеет не более двух потомков.

Сам алгоритм, который выдаёт неправильное решение

```
 /**  
 * Calculate sum of all right children for every node  
 * @param root node of the tree. Use it to traverse the tree.
 * @return node of the tree where for every node is computed sum of it's all right children  
 */

public Node rightSum(Node root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (root.right != null) {
        root.sumOfAllRight += root.sumOfAllRight + root.right.value;
    }
    rightSum(root.right);
    rightSum(root.left);
    return root;
}
```

Class Node :

```
    public class Node {  

Node left = null;
Node right = null;
long value;
long sumOfAllRight = 0;
long sumOfAllChildren = 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  rightSum(root.right);
  rightSum(root.left);
  root.sumOfAllRight = root.right.sumOfAllChildren;        
  root.sumOfAllChildren = root.value + root.sumOfAllRight + root.left.sumOfAllChildren;
```